# Listbox in UpdatePanel doesn't trigger the second time

Tags: c#, asp.net

The list box in the below updatePanel triggers the postback only once, for example if I select pre-Purchase on ddlroot it loads the appropriate data on ddlchild, but if I select post-order again it doesn't load the data needed.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" runat="server">
 <Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlroot" EventName="TextChanged" />
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlchild" EventName="Textchanged" />
 </Triggers>
 <ContentTemplate>
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <asp:ListBox ID="ddlroot" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlroot_SelectedIndexChanged">
 <asp:ListItem Value="pre-purchase" Text="Pre-Purchase"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="post-purchase" Text="Post-Purchase"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:ListBox>
 </td>
 <td>
 <asp:ListBox ID="ddlchild" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Below would be the server side code where based on the ddlroot selection the data will be fetched from MySql database,

```
    protected void ddlroot_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ddlchild.Items.Clear();

        string MyConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
        if (ddlroot.SelectedValue == "pre-purchase")
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
            {

                using (MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd1.CommandText = "select distinct(prePurchase) from prepurchase WHERE prePurchase IS NOT NULL";
                    cmd1.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    using (MySqlDataReader sdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr1.Read())
                        {
                            ListItem item1 = new ListItem();
                            item1.Text = sdr1["prePurchase"].ToString();
                            item1.Value = sdr1["prePurchase"].ToString();
                            ddlchild.Items.Add(item1);
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        else if(ddlroot.SelectedValue == "post-purchase")
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
            {

                using (MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd1.CommandText = "select distinct(postPurchase) from prepurchase WHERE postPurchase IS NOT NULL";
                    cmd1.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    using (MySqlDataReader sdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr1.Read())
                        {
                            ListItem item1 = new ListItem();
                            item1.Text = sdr1["postPurchase"].ToString();
                            item1.Value = sdr1["postPurchase"].ToString();
                            ddlchild.Items.Add(item1);
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        //UpdatePanel5.Update();

    }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with your code. Have you used the debugger? `ddlroot_SelectedIndexChanged` gets hit a second time. Is there more code, for example in `Page_Load`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yep it does get hit the second time, only the data doesn't show on the listbox and Page_load is empty.

Comment: Again, have you used the debugger to see what happens? Maybe there's an swallowed exception or something else wrong. Does the Child-ListBox get filled correctly at serverside but the content is just not updated at clientside?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes the child listbox gets filled correctly on serverside but the content is not loading on client side

Comment: @prkash, add this attribute `UpdateMode="Conditional"` to your `<asp:UpdatePanel>` like `<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">`

Comment: @ershoaib Hi bro, I already tried that but it's still not working, it is because of the bootstrap I added for the listbox it seems, without the bootstrap it is working fine. Is it possible to use bootstrap/jquery without affecting it?

Comment: @prkash, where did u add this bootstrap to listbox item? I didn't see in your code.

Comment: @prkash, is your problem solved or not?  All going good?